# How to eager load multiple belongsTo relationships against the same table?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eager-loading

With the following model, a user has 2x relationships to a car. Both point to the same table but use a different field (daily_car_id + weekend_car_id):

```
class User extends Model
    public function dailyCar() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Car::class, 'daily_car_id', 'id');
    }
    public function weekendCar() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Car::class, 'weekend_car_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

This all works perfectly except for eager loading:

```
User::with(['dailyCar', 'weekendCar'])->findOrFail($id);
```

**Expected**

```
# 10 is the weekend car id and 12 is the daily
SELECT * FROM `car` WHERE `car`.`id` in (10, 12)
```

**Actual result (<del>incorrect</del> unexpected)**

```
# 10 is the weekend car id and 12 is the daily
SELECT * FROM `car` WHERE `car`.`id` in (10)
SELECT * FROM `car` WHERE `car`.`id` in (12)
```

Is there a way to eager load when using multiple belongsTo relationships against the same table?

Comment: No, there isn't a way for Eloquent to merge queries across relations..

Comment: Hmm, it makes sense I guess. I can probably work around it by running my own query and merging it together

Answer (score 0):

You can change you eager load to this:

```
$user = User::find($id);
$car = Car::where('id', $user->dailyCar->id)->where('id', $user->weekendCar->id)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks @Albarra Naufala. You're not wrong, though it doesn't really leverage eager loading which is what I was going for. I actually ended up with a solution like yours (Wrapped up in a repository pattern) after I found out it wasn't directly possible with eager loading. Thanks again